# What is the opposite of "caching"?

Tags: caching, terminology, naming

As far as I can understand, the act of caching something is moving something from a slower memory (e.g. RAM) to a faster memory (e.g. Cache), when you want to access that thing a lot of times.

What if there is something in a faster memory (e.g. RAM), but you want to store it on a slower memory (e.g. Hard Disk) because you aren't using it a lot?

Is there a word for that action? Just "storing" doesn't seem right. Couldn't find a better word on Google, just by describing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The used term for that is Swapped out or Rolled out
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging)